# What's the difference between Error and Exception in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling

It seems that `Error` and `Exception` are the same thing: both of them can be thrown with a `throw` statement and caught with a `try catch` block.

Comment: A little bit of googling is never wrong, http://java67.blogspot.nl/2012/12/difference-between-error-vs-exception.html

Comment: ""exceptions" refers to errors (runtime) that can be trapped and controlled. as opposed to "errors" that are just bad syntax and break the compiler fully... " - https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/difference-between-error-exception.1324844/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**JavaScript syntax**

Errors and exceptions are syntactically synonymous in JavaScript. The language only implements the `Error` keyword (through `window.Error`). You may define custom errors, using the `Error.constructor`, which takes `name` and `message` as parameters.

**JavaScript Error**

There is also the line number sugar that can be used to trace bug occurrences inside the code. JavaScript only has `Error`. Whether you hear people talking about `Exceptions` or `Errors`, in JavaScript they refer to the same thing.

Browsers make a distinction: `ReferenceError` (when accessing a variable with a name that doesn't exist in the heap, or when you make a typo(more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError).), `TypeError` is also a known JS error, more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError).

**JavaScript Exception**

A known JavaScript `Exception` is `DOM Exception 8`. It occurs when you access an object that is not ready, such as an `XMLHttpRequest` that has not completed the request.

**Implementation**

When using `try catch` or `try catch finally` blocks, you will deal with both JavaScript `Exception` and `Error`. Code-wise the difference has no impact.

Behind the scenes, the browsers use the same `window.Error` `constructor`. An `Exception` is an `Error` instance with a `name` and `message` that contain "Exception".

Try: `var myCustomError = new Error("myException", "An exception occurred.");`. "Exception" is text in a string. More on `Error` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

**Convention**

By convention, there is a difference between `Error` and `Exception`. An `Error` indicates a clear violation. A `TypeError` or `ReferenceError` means you are not following the language specs.

An `Exception` is thrown when you access an `XMLHttpRequest` response before it is complete. `Error` is a "you broke the law" shout and `Exception` is an "Almost there!" pad on the shoulder. Hope the analogy helps!

Comment: A subtle difference that's bitten me is that DOMException's message property is read-only, where all the other errors I've seen have a message property that's writable. There may be more that are read-only, I just haven't encountered them.

Comment: The convention bit is something I don't agree with.

Comment: "The language only implements the Error keyword". Other than "Error", there is also an implementation of "DOMException" developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException. Besides the generic Error constructor, there are other core error constructors in JavaScript like rangeError, ReferenceError, SyntaxError etc

Comment: `Try: var myCustomError = new Error("myException", "An exception occurred.");` Can't tell if the specification has changed, but as of now, the `Error` object constructor, apparently only takes a single parameter. The `Error message` with its name being the generic `Error` name by default. In order to have such a level of fine control i.e. specifying a name and a message, a class should be used instead.

Answer (score 22):

Based on the [lecture](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp), the Errors are thrown by JavaScript engine and exception are thrown by developer. it is only naming convention.

- JavaScript throws Errors
- Developers throws Exceptions

In technical aspect is the same structure (thing).

Comment: that was crisp :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that an error is something serious that you should not try to catch
An exception is something that should be caught, in so far as it is possible to handle it.

An error is when something wrong or invalid happens in the code. It can cause a memory error, it is something that should never happen and can't be treated.

Whereas an exception throws something when certain conditions are met in the code. It may not correspond to a real error.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    throw "throwing string";
} catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
}
```

If we run this code, we will observe that ***catch*** clause will receive ***whatever we throw*** using throw keyword. It means if we throw string we will receive string, if we throw object we will receive object, if we throw number we will receive number.

***Note:*** So if we throw Error we will receive Error.

Hence the conclusion is whatever we throw using ***throw keyword*** will be considered as exception. If we don't catch(or handle) it then our Javascript code blows up.